# Parsing directory for UNIX permissions to migrate

Tags: scripting, permissions

I have an interesting problem. I have a NAS device that supports mixed mode: files on it are all jumbled up, some with NTFS style ACL's and some with UNIX style permissions. I have migrated data from that NAS device to another that supports mixed permissions, and all of the permissions are in NTFS style ACL's due to the way I migrated. I want to copy the UNIX permissions from the original source data and apply them to the destination data. Here is the pseudo-code

for each file and directory recursively down a mount point
if its not a Windows file (owner GID and UID != 99)
read the permissions, UID and GID and write them to a file with the filename
Apply those permissions to the destination data

At this point I am having trouble with the second of those 4 lines.

I am recursing using find, and then running a script against each entry returned. The find command is:

```
find /mnt/test -exec /home/permchange2 \{\} \;
```

And the script /home/permchange2 is below. The problem is that when I leave the IF statement there, I only get output to the screen, nothing to file. When I comment it out, everything goes to the file like I want it, but it is including the files with gid=99 and uid=99 which I do not want. Something must be wrong with my IF statement but I can't figure out what....

```
#!/bin/bash

date=`date +%m-%d-%H%M%S`
outfile=/home/perms-${date}.log

#get uid and gid exclude windows files
uid=$(stat "$1" | grep "Access: (" | awk -F[\(\/]  '{print $4}' | awk '{sub(/^[ \t]+/, "")};1')
gid=$(stat "$1" | grep "Access: (" | awk -F[\(\/]  '{print $6}' | awk '{sub(/^[ \t]+/, "")};1')
echo "uid="$uid
echo "gid="$gid
if [[ uid==99 && gid==99 ]]; then
        exit 0;
fi

#write the filename
echo $1 >> $outfile

#get permissions
stat "$1" | grep "Access: (" | awk -F[\(\/]  '{print $2}' >> $outfile

#write out uid
echo $uid >> $outfile

#write out gid
echo $gid >> $outfile

#echo newline
echo -e "\n"
```

Comment: if [[ $uid==99 && $gid==99 ]]; then
        exit 0;
fi

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out. I had to use "-eq" instead of "=="